# How can an American football team tie with another team?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, tie-breaker

I am a football beginner, but still a fan. I've been wondering how could an American football team tie with another team. I know that there is OT (overtime), and I'm not sure if the game ends with a tie after one OT.

Could somebody explain to me how can an American football team tie with another team?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the NFL, if the score is tied at the end of the fourth quarter, the game goes into overtime (OT).

The current overtime rules follow a **modified sudden death** format.  In this format, the first team to score wins the game, unless a field goal is scored on the first possession of overtime.  In that event, the team that did not score is allowed one possession to try to score.

Overtime is a 10-minute period.  (Before 2017, overtime was 15 minutes.) During the regular season, if the entire 10-minute overtime period is played and the teams are still tied, the game ends in a tie.

During the playoffs, however, tie games are not allowed.  If the overtime period ends with no result, another overtime period is begun, and the game will continue until there is a winner.

Sources:

- NFL.com: [NFL overtime rules](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/09000d5d827ee2c0/article/nfl-overtime-rules)
- Sports Illustrated: [How does NFL overtime work?](https://www.si.com/nfl/2016/nfl-overtime-rules)